# Web font that supports some basic music symbols

Tags: website-design, fonts

I am working on a web page that displays some music note names such as "B", "Bb" (B flat), or C# (C sharp). For a better readability I would prefer to display the correct flat and sharp symbols.

It seems that the standard sans-serif fonts such as Arial or Helvetica do not support these symbols, which leads me to the conclusion that I need to find a web font that looks similar to the widespread sans-serifs (Arial, Helvetica) and in addition has these two symbols.

Q1: Do you know of any such web font?

Q2: Or was I completely mistaken and the Arial and Helvetica actually *do* support musical notation symbols, and they happen to be in the same position for both of these fonts?

Comment: Very view fonts implement more than a tiny handful of unicode symbols. Might consider some specific [music fonts](http://www.fontspace.com/dvm-publications/metdemo). I know they exist but I don't know which to recommend.

Comment: Standard fonts such as Arial and Helvetica *do* support these symbols. See [my answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/8027/155) as proof of this, as those are the fonts actually used here on this site..!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using unicode characters, this will be available for a wide range of fonts.

Here you can see how to program these symbols in HTML as unicode, and how it is displayed here in the font used on this page:

`&#9837;` will show as:  ♭

`&#9838;` will show as:  ♮

`&#9839;` will show as:  ♯

You can also copy the characters directly and paste them in as you like:

`♭♮♯` will show as: ♭♮♯

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to know [where to look](http://www.myfonts.com/search/music/fonts/).

There are at least three available as web fonts: Music Sheets, P22 Music and P22 Music Pro.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209549/web-font-that-supports-some-basic-music-symbols

Comment: Thank's Andrew. What I was looking for is a web font that renders the ASCII set (at least) just like a sans-serif font does but provides a FLAT and SHARP sign in its Dingbats set.

Comment: OK. If you go to http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/miscellaneous_symbols.html you can test fonts. Unicode 266D, 266E and 266F appear to be the right symbols, and they might be read out correctly by screen-readers. In fact I wonder if &#9837; will be rendered as a flat by browsers anyway.